# Firebase for android and iOS application

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I've been looking into implementing firebase for my mobile applications. I understand how to set it up on the applications. Followed some tutorials

- https://www.sitepoint.com/creating-a-cloud-backend-for-your-android-app-using-firebase
- https://www.androidhive.info/2016/06/android-getting-started-firebase-simple-login-registration-auth/

My questions are:

1. Can I authenticate my users by only username or uuid no password required?
2. How can I set up the database to get data from my current server.
3. Can I push different notifications to each user and have the option to send to a group or all users?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes you can achieve this using Firebase Anonymous Authentication for [Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth) and for [iOs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/anonymous-auth). IMHO, is my actual favorite because you can actually log in a user without getting any information from them, `no email`, `no password` and no `OAuth` authorization necessary. You need just to click a button an log in.
   An important thing to remember is that when the user decides to become a real user, you can merge those two accounts into a real account.
2. You can easily get data from your server accordingly to your operation system, Android or iOs.
3. For push notification i recomand you using [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/). Is a cross-platform messaging solution that lets you reliably deliver messages at no cost.

Hope it helps.